# Do we need enumeration to find the maximal number of steps a special Turing machine can make?

Tags: functions, computational-complexity, turing-machines

Consider a special Turing machine that only needs two places on a tape, in other words , the head switches between two places until the machine halts. I am only interested in the case of two symbols.

The halting problem is decidable for such machines because if a configuration is repeated , the machine will never halt, and this must eventually happen, unless the machine halts or leaves the two places.

Let $f(n)$ be the maximum number such a halting machine can make , if it has $n$ states.

> Can we determine $f(n)$ without enumerating all Turing machines ?
>
> If yes, can we also find a machine doing the maximum number of steps efficiently ?

For $2,3,4,5$ , the best machines I found , do $4,9,14,17$ steps respectively. Enumerating all machines will soon be no more feasible.

I used a very simple variant of a generic algorithm (I varied some steps of the best machine, hoping to arrive at a better machine), but there should be a more efficient approach.

Comment: So assuming it uses 0's and 1's ... does it start on 00?

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, exactly that. Start is $00$ and we the symbols $0$ and $1$